# request.POST.getlist() returns empty list

Tags: django, django-views

I am not able to access my inputs thorugh request.POST.getlist() method, and when I run my program, all other fields are okay and I can see the result but when it comes to choices it return empty list.

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    teacher_get = request.POST.get('teacher')
    department_get = request.POST.get('department')
    subject_get = request.POST.get('subject')
    answer_list = []
    print(teacher_get)
    print(department_get)
    print(subject_get)
    answer = request.POST.getlist("question_{{question.id}}")
    print(answer)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Ahmad
Software Engineering
Programming
[]
[26/Nov/2020 15:48:12] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 2353
```

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<form action="{% url 'index'%}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<select name="teacher">
{% for question in question %}
    <ol>{{ question.question }}</ol>
    
    {% for choice in rating_choices %}
     <input type="radio" name="question_{{question.id}}" value="{{choice.0}}">{{choice.1}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %} <br>

<input type="submit" value="Vote">
```

Comment: The name of the item is not `{{question_question.id}}`, this will be *interpolated*, so if `question.id` was `25`, it will thus use `question_25`.

Comment: It is about 15 questions, I want to get the value of all inputs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request will not contain any values for the `question_{{question.id}}` name, since the template is *rendered*. This means that at the side of the client, it will look for a `Question` with `.id` equal to 25 as `name="question_25"`.

You thus will need to reconstruct the `Question`s, and read these individually, for example something like:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    teacher_get = request.POST.get('teacher')
    department_get = request.POST.get('department')
    subject_get = request.POST.get('subject')
    answer_list = []
    print(teacher_get)
    print(department_get)
    print(subject_get)
    for question in Question.objects.all():
        answer = request.POST.get(f'question_{question.pk}')
        print(answer)
```

or you can look for all the keys that start with `question_`, and thus retrieve the values for all picked choices of the `question_…` keys:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    teacher_get = request.POST.get('teacher')
    department_get = request.POST.get('department')
    subject_get = request.POST.get('subject')
    answer_list = []
    print(teacher_get)
    print(department_get)
    print(subject_get)
    answers = [v for q, v in request.POST.items() if q.startswith('question_')]
```